# Mplayer slower than other video players

Tags: x11, mplayer

I have as my main media/video player my own (built from source by myself, including all the necessary libraries) mplayer

However, one of the problems that I have with it, it's his low relative performance when compared to the system default media player (totem) and with some customized version of mplayer that runs in another linux.

For instance, a 1280x720 video (scaled to 1024x768), used between 65-89% of cpu use in a few minutes of observation. This with mplayer automatically re-scaling it to 1024x768.

Totem has a greater range of cpu utilization (like 34 to 86%) when also re-scaling the video. Perhaps, its because it does not play it smoothly (it has fairly frequent very small fractions of time where the video stops playing). The video is not really playable on Totem when compared with Mplayer, despite lower cpu utilization.

However, this was for a HD video.

For a 640x360 scaled to 1024x768, mplayer used mainly 35 to 40% of cpu use in slow moving scenes and between high 30s to about 45-46% in faster scenes.

Totem on other hand uses something like 12-20% cpu in the slow scenes and from a bit less than twenty to about 30% in the faster scenes.

The mplayer of the other linux is by far the faster of the three. On the 640x360 video, it uses around 8.5-9.0% of cpu use in the slower scenes, with peaks around 13%. On the faster scenes, it usually goes from low 10s to around 16-17%, perhaps a bit more in a very few selected moments. Xorg use seems to be considerably less, around 3.3 to 4% most of time, against 6-7%, perhaps 8% of the xorg on the other OS

So my goal is to bring my mplayer performance close to mplayer from the other OS (perhaps xorg performance too)

Feel to make any questions about my system.

Comment: Is there an advantage for me?

Comment: "works much better". Why? What's the difference?

Comment: Mplayer is not "close to my heart" or any nonsense that you seems to like to mutter. Its a video player that achieves its basic intended goal, which for me is to play videos. But not efficiently (too slow). You are, however, asking to spend a considerably amount of effort to use another video player that may not have any meaningful advantages over it? Who is irrational here?

Comment: I forgot to add that mplayer is only partially fullfilling its goal of playing video, as it's not playing subtitles. But I did not try to solve this issue yet.

Comment: Finally, to make you satisfied, I will give a look at mpv if and only if I cannot solve the problems mentioned above., even though I am not particularly optimistic about the chances of it not suffering the same problems of mplayer.

Comment: Finally, your link doesn't work on my web browser.